# SP500, Dow Jones and Nasdaq tickers won't work Python

Tags: python, stock, ticker, quandl, pandas-datareader

The tickers for SP500, Dow Jones, and NASDAQ being ^GSPC, ^IXIC, and ^DJI, no longer work.

```
import datetime, quandl
from pandas_datareader import data, wb

start = datetime.datetime(2016,8,20)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 20)

sp500 = data.DataReader('^GSPC','google', start, end)  # S&P 500
nq = data.DataReader('^IXIC','google', start, end)  # NASDAQ
dj = data.DataReader('^DJI','google', start, end)   # Dow
```

I've also tried quandl, and the same problem occurred.

```
sp500 = quandl.get("WIKI/^GSPC", trim_start= start, trim_end=end)
dji = quandl.get("WIKI/INDEX_DJI", trim_start=start, trim_end=end)
```

Any idea if there is away around this problem? Presumably these tickers are out of date, and there are new ones for each of them. Downloading them isn't very Pythonic or cool :/
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: They're not out of date.  Google has went the way of Yahoo and simply restricted access to its data.  Notice the [page](https://finance.google.com/finance?q=%5EINX&ei=ApOnWdjfHIWNeN_9p5gM) for the S&P 500 no longer has a "historical data" tab.  It's this .csv file that `DataReader` reads, and Google no longer makes the file available.  When you get a `RemoteDataError` it's because that .csv is no longer publicly available.

Comment: Hi Brad. Fortunately Yahoo finance still allows for downloading of the S&P 500 as a csv file, same with DJIA. Even though Yahoo, and now Google are restricting access to their data, I thought at least Quandl might have been a viable source, but seems not.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing the Dow Jones Index use:

```
dji = quandl.get("BCB/UDJIAD1", 
              trim_start='2018-03-01', 
              trim_end='2018-03-31')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to get the data in 'open, high, low, close' format?